# JSON File cannot convert into class object in C#

Tags: c#, json

I want to display list of SyncEntity which contains another list of EntityField in my class, but I got only "JSONReader.SyncEntity" as output.

How can I get output as list of SyncEntity?

Below is my code Snippet.

```
namespace JSONReader
{
public class SyncEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Modified { get; set; }
    public List<EntityField> EntityFields { get; set; }
}
public class EntityField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public List<SyncEntity> SyncEntity { get; set; }
}
}
```

Below is my main class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ExecuteEmployeeSearch();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ExecuteEmployeeSearch()
    {
        List<SyncEntity> datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SyncEntity>>(File.ReadAllText(@"E:\\JsonDemo.json"));
       datalist.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

Below is my JSON format:

```
[{
"SyncEntity": [{
    "Name": "Vivek",
    "Id": "24",
    "Modified": "30-Dec-2017",
    "EntityFields": [{
            "Name": "Absolute No",
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "string"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Description",
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "String"
        }
    ]
}]
}]
```

What did I miss to get List of SyncEntity in that List of Entity Field?

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your JSON suggests that you need to ask for a list of `RootObject`s when deserializing. Try this

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(File.ReadAllText(@"E:\\JsonDemo.json"));
data.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

I'm guessing that you also need to define the `SyncEntity` as an object, not as an array inside your `JSON` file. It makes more sense if it looked something like this

```
[{
    "Name": "Vivek",
    "Id": "24",
    "Modified": "30-Dec-2017",
    "EntityFields": [{
            "Name": "Absolute No",
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "string"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Description",
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "String"
        }
    ]
}]
```

In the above case, your new model classes should have the following structure

```
public class EntityField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class SyncEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Modified { get; set; }
    public List<EntityField> EntityFields { get; set; }
}
```

After this, you can now deserialize into `List<SyncEntity>`. In order to display your data, you should iterate through this list and print the relevant properties

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SyncEntity>>(File.ReadAllText(@"E:\\JsonDemo.json"));
data.ForEach(se =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("The sync entity name is " + se.Name + ". And it has the following fields:");
    se.EntityFields.ForEach(ef =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} of type {1} with value {2}", ef.Name, ef.Type, ef.Value);
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Octavian for your quick reply but it also gave the old output same as "JSONReader.RootObject"

Comment: @MayurChaudhari That is happening because you are calling `Console.WriteLine` with the object as the argument. Can you change the JSON structure, or you need to stick with the current one?

Comment: what structure do you mean..I dont have any idea about another structure. I am new to Json and if i wish to stick with current structure then what can i do for that and if I change the structure then can My class defination be changed???

Comment: @MayurChaudhari Please see if my updated answer helps you achieve your goal :)